# Setting the title of the page using the model from the route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I’m a bit puzzled about setting the title element from my router using the [ember-cli-document-title](https://github.com/kimroen/ember-cli-document-title) add-on. It works just fine if I pass it a function or a string, but I’m trying to access the current model via `modelFor`.

It works when the page first loads, but then, when I transition to another route, it changes to ‘undefined’. If I go to a previously visited route the value is populated. It appears that at the time of display, the value is not yet populated. How can I wait for DS to have the attributes on my model instance before trying to assign it to the title?

I had attempted calling `reload()` on my model, and then returning the resulting promise instead, `ember-cli-document-title` doesn't seem to like promises in the `title` attribute.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  title: function() {
    let model = this.modelFor(this.routeName)
    let title = model.get('title')
    return `${title} | Some More Text`
  }
}
```

### Update: Just found an important detail

One of the first thing my app does is fetch an index of a bunch of posts from the server. For performance, some attributes are not included in the `index`, but are in the `show` action.

I've realized that this problem has something to do with the fact that these models are partially loaded. It seems like `ember-cli-document-title` immediately tries to change the title without waiting for other attributes to load.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `titleToken`. The default `titleToken` is your model.

The `titleToken` is passed in an array to your `title` function. So you can do this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  title([model]) {
    const title = model.get('title');
    return `${title} | Some More Text`;
  }
}
```

Comment: What you're saying makes sense. It's more in alignment with the intentions of the plugin. I've changed it so that the leafmost router now has the titleToken attribute, and the `application.js` route has a `title` attribute that uses the token. But, I still have the issue that properties on my model instance aren't loaded and show up as `undefined`.

Comment: normal attributes, not relationships? are you doing anything weird with your adapter/serializer? Can you reproduce in a twiddle or git repo?

Comment: Thanks Lux. I just added an important update to the question above. If that's not of enough use, I'll try to reproduce in a twiddle.

Comment: ember-data does not support partial loaded models. Don't do that! This will always lead to trouble. If you need to split your data create two models with a 1:1 relationship! Here ember waits for the promise to resolve, but if the promise is resolved the model is considered `done`.

Comment: If you work your last comment into the answer, I will mark it as accepted :)  On a side note, I ended up just using `findRecord` with the `{reload: true}` option. It works, and it's a small project, I'm happy with it. Thanks again!